# Angular direct DOM access?

Tags: angular

I know this has been asked a zillion times and received answers in many cases.  I believe I've read most of them.  Unfortunately, everything I can find on this

1. Simply states `ElementRef.nativeElement` is bad, don't use it, but doesn't offer much in the way of *current*, *valid* alternatives.
2. Is old, still talking a lot about renderer being deprecated and other beta issues.
3. Covers a very specific use case and is not particularly applicable outside that use case

So I'm trying to wrap my head around where things stand **currently**.  v5 was recently released and things have in general stabilized across many fronts.  **Current** is important - we're getting ready to start a brand new project with no legacy anything behind it, so we want to start as clean as possible.

Is it safe to take the following approaches:

- In a **directive** you are going to have a valid ElementRef (or else the Directive code wouldn't be running), and therefore accessing it's `nativeElement` property is safe.  Almost every directive example in the official docs does this
- Using `nativeElement` in conjunction with `Renderer2` (for example 
  `this.renderer2.setStyle(elm.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'red');`) is OK  because Renderer2 somehow magically makes it work (Renderer2 is another thing I can't find really good docs on how it performs this magic)
- Using `nativeElement` is always OK if you are not and will never be, doing server side rendering or using web workers (please disregard the fact that we can't predict the future)
- In all other cases, put a template reference variable (#myElement) on the element and use `@ViewChild('myElement')`, `@ViewChildren('myElement') myElements: QueryList<ElementRef>;`, or similar with `@ContentChild/ren('myElement',{read:ElementRef })` to get and use the element(s)
- Always practice good, defensive coding and ensure that you actually have a valid `nativeElement` before trying to use it.

Note that in most of these cases, we're still using `nativeElement` they just vary in how we access it.  To me, that means `nativeElement` itself isn't a problem, it's all in how you get it and use it.
Am I missing anything?  Any problems with any of the above?  I'm trying to get fact, not opinion, so any links to official docs, or even really good, current blog posts would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: I am using same thing to access the nativeElement and working on canvas, here is some additional info i know.

using nativeElement is ok when you guard your code correctly with isPlatformBrowser when using server side rendering. see the angular universal https://github.com/angular/universal

here is the renderer2 api the docs kinda missing some of api description you need to test it before deciding to use it. https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

here is a good read also to create dynamic component https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @AdeNovan.  I'll look into isPlatformBrowser.  I've seen the Renderer2 docs you linked to, but they don't say much, and nothing about nativeElement.  :-(  Also, I'm not looking to build components dynamically, but isn't DynamicComponentLoader deprecated?

Comment: That docs i linked is already use ComponentFactoryResolver to dynamicly create an component that can passed to Renderer2. The documentation on creating and compiling on runtime is just bad. The transition from server side rendering to client side is lack of documentation too, but in past i try to play with the api and its working without manipulate the dom directly. Need to go throught to Angular Api before creating the view like Render2 and ComponentFactoryResolver. It just like telling angular we want to mess with dom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you should prefer the `Renderer2` service when you need to change DOM element properties. But do not use the `Renderer2` to change DOM hierarchy. Instead use the templating technique and view containers.

> Using nativeElement is always OK if you are not and will never be,
>   doing server side rendering or using web workers (please disregard the
>   fact that we can't predict the future)

Yes. Or mobile devices.

> To me, that means nativeElement itself isn't a problem, it's all in
>   how you get it and use it.

Different platforms can implement access to DOM elements in different ways. For example, the `Renderer2` service inside the webworker, instead of calling native DOM methods (which doesn't exist inside the webworker) simply transmits the message to main UI thread. If you use `nativeElement` directly, you get an error.